# Leaflet and Flexbox Design Issues

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, flexbox

I'm trying to implement a flexbox design where on the left-hand side of the browser window I have a side bar, and on the right hand side I have a Leaflet map.

There are two issues I'm having:

1. If I try to change the positioning of the map using the position selector in CSS, it makes the map appear in the top left of the page and overlays above all content.
2. I generally cannot get the map to cover the entire open area to the right of the sidebar, which is what I want.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="flexbox">
    <header class="flexbox-header">
        <div class="Header Header--cozy" role="banner">
            MyHeader
        </div>
    </header>

    <main class="flexbox-body">
        <article class="flexbox-content">
            <div id="map"></div>
        </article>
        <nav class="flexbox-control-bar u-textCenter">
            <strong>Navigation</strong>
        </nav>
    </main>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.flexbox {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flexbox-header,
.flexbox-footer {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: none;
    -ms-flex: none;
    flex: none;
}
.flexbox-body {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flexbox-content {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
}
.flexbox-control-bar {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 0;
    -webkit-order: -1;
    -ms-flex-order: -1;
    order: -1;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .flexbox-body {
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .flexbox-content {
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -webkit-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
        padding: 0 2em;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .flexbox-control-bar,
    .flexbox-ads {
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -webkit-flex: 0 0 20em;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 20em;
        flex: 0 0 20em;
    }
}
```

I have an example here, on JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nr09863c/4/

Thank you!